# TFS, MSBuild, and VS.PHP

Tags: php, tfs, msbuild

So I am using Visual Studio 2008 and VS.PHP 2.9 with Team Foundation Server to develop my PHP application.  Unfortunately, I have to use TFS and Visual Studio - no switching to Subversion or Git.

I am in the process of writing an MSBuild script to, whenever files are checked into a certain directory in the tree, get the latest version of the modules, put them in a ZIP archive, and then FTP the ZIP archive to a testing server, where they're then unzipped and processed.

If I configure a build with TFS and use its default build methods, nothing really works as my .sln file doesn't contain any of the things MSBuild expects - after all, there's nothing to compile.  So, I'm writing my own build script to get the latest versions of the files before ZIPping and FTPing.

My question: anyone know the best way to get the latest version of certain files from TFS from MSBuild?  I know how to do it from the command prompt with `tf.exe`, but I'd really prefer to do it from the MSBuild script.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found the answer:

http://blogs.msdn.com/nagarajp/archive/2005/10/21/483590.aspx

Comment: Also, as it turns out, it's better to just do it from the command line.

Heh.